# Call Sub from Form Button

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to call a sub from the current sheet from a user form button but get the following error; 'Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined".

This is the code

```
Private Sub form_addDate_clickSubmit_Click()
    Dim WKB As Workbook
    Dim SHT_EDIT As Worksheet
    Set WKB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set SHT_EDIT = WKB.Sheets("EDIT")
    Call loadData
    'Tried various other ways such as SHT_EDIT.loadData
End Sub
```

The loadData sub is public.

Thanks

Comment: You might have an error in loadData. Like an object not defined or smth else

Comment: And the `loadData` sub is in a `Worksheet` module or a normal module?

Comment: Also is your button really called `form_addDate_clickSubmit`?  That looks like two procedure names - `form_addDate_click` and `Submit_Click`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your Sub `loadData` is in a Sheet Module.

You can call it with `[SHT_EDIT].loadData`, assuming that the *CodeName* of the sheet is `SHT_EDIT` (the code name is the name shown in the VBA Project explorer, not the name of the sheet in Excel.

A better solution is to move the Sub into a regular Module.

Comment: You should put all your code containing logic into Modules (or classes) and keep only the Events in sheet or form modules.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I code my command buttons on a worksheet:

```
Option Explicit
Public WS As Worksheet     ' global Worksheet object

Private Sub InsertNextWeek_Button1_Click()
'Button to call the Insert Next Week subprocedure

  'Save the current active worksheet
  Set WS = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

  'Run procedure to Insert 7 new rows for Next Week
  Call Insert_NextWeek

  'Make this worksheet is left as the active worksheet
  WS.Activate

  'clear worksheet variable
  Set WS = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub PublishRunStats_Button6_Click()
'Button to call the Publish RunStats subprocedure

  'Save the current active worksheet
  Set WS = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

  'Run procedure to Save the Run Stats worksheet to a new workbook
  Call Publish_RunStats_Sheet

  'Make this worksheet is left as the active worksheet
  WS.Activate

  'clear worksheet variable
  Set WS = Nothing
End Sub
```

The called sub-procedures are coded as Public in Module1 of the same Workbook.
The global WS object is used in each command button sub-procedure to ensure that my display focus ends up back on the same worksheet as the command button just clicked.